# How to add Desktop Support to Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile Project

Tags: mobile, desktop, kotlin-multiplatform

Using Android Studio with the Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile plugin, I have created a KMM project, which provides support for Android and iOS.

However, I would also like to be able to use the same code base and UI to deploy to create a desktop app. Is that possible? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, this tutorial details how to do it, albeit in a quite roundabout way that took me several days to complete:

https://www.kodeco.com/books/kotlin-multiplatform-by-tutorials/v1.0/chapters/1-introduction

Because of that, I have taken the liberty to creating a short summary for how you can create a basic project setup for a Desktop/Android/iOS app:

1. Install the `Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile` and `Compose Multiplatform IDE Support` plugins in Android Studio
2. Create a new `Kotlin Multiplatform App` project (under `Phone and Tablet`)

   - For the following points, I am going to assume the project name is "My Project" and the package name is `com.domain.project`
3. In the `shared/build.gradle.kts`, in the `kotlin` block, after `android()`, add:

   - ```kotlin
     jvm("desktop"){
         compilations.all {
             kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
         }
     }
     ```
4. Add a new `desktop` folder at the top level of the app
5. Add a new file `build.gradle.kts` into the `desktop` folder, and fill it with this content:

   - ```kotlin
     import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
     import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

     plugins {
         kotlin("multiplatform")
         id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.2.2"
     }

     group = "com.domain.project"
     version = "1.0.0"

     kotlin {
         jvm {
             withJava()
             compilations.all {
                 kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
             }
         }
         sourceSets {
             val jvmMain by getting {
                 kotlin.srcDirs("src/jvmMain/kotlin")
                 dependencies {
                     implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                     api(compose.runtime)
                     api(compose.foundation)
                     api(compose.material)
                     api(compose.ui)
                     api(compose.materialIconsExtended)

                     implementation(project(":shared"))
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     compose.desktop {
         application {
             mainClass = "MainKt"
             nativeDistributions {
                 targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
                 packageName = "MyProject"
                 macOS {
                     bundleID = "com.domain.project"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ```
6. On the top level, in the `settings.gradle.kts` add `include(":desktop")` at the very end
7. Click on "sync now" (Or `File > Sync project with gradle files`)

   - After the sync, the `desktop` folder should now be recognized as a module, indicated by a little square at the bottom right of the folder icon
8. In the `desktop` module, create the folder chain `src/jvmMain/kotlin`
9. In the just created `kotlin` folder create the Kotlin file `Main`, and fill it as follows:

   - ```kotlin
     import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
     import androidx.compose.material.Surface
     import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
     import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
     import androidx.compose.ui.window.application
     import androidx.compose.ui.window.rememberWindowState
     import androidx.compose.material.*

     fun main() {
         application {
             val windowState = rememberWindowState()

             Window(
                 onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
                 state = windowState,
                 title = "My Project"
             ) {
                 Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                     Text(text = "Welcome to my Project")
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     ```
10. Add a run configuration of type `Gradle` with the following settings:

    - **Name**: "Desktop"
    - **Run**: "run"
    - **Gradle Project:** "project:desktop"
11. Create the file `shared/src/desktopMain/kotiln/com.domain.project/Platform.kt`, and fill it with this:

    - ```kotlin
      package com.domain.project

      class DesktopPlatform : Platform {
          override val name: String = "Desktop"
      }

      actual fun getPlatform(): Platform = DesktopPlatform()
      ```
12. You should now be able to run the desktop app

After that, you can then create shared Compose views that will work on both android and desktop. Chapter 5 of aforementioned tutorial covers that:

https://www.kodeco.com/books/kotlin-multiplatform-by-tutorials/v1.0/chapters/5-developing-ui-compose-multiplatform

In addition, here's a bare-bones version of a project that I created using the above steps:

https://github.com/KiraResari/ceal-chronicler/releases/tag/basic-android-and-desktop-app

Answer (score 2):

By now it can be used https://kmp.jetbrains.com/ to generate project for all needed platforms.